# Is it possible to dynamically create "azurerm" providers?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to create multiple azure_rm providers, from a variable list.
Trying with "count" is not possible, I got the message "reserved for future usage".

Technicaly describing, the section that I would like to dynamic create is:

```
provider "azurerm" {  
  features {}
  subscription_id = "1d1a56ed-681f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  alias = "spoke1"
}
```

I tried also with for_each, but also not possible, since for_each creates only a section, not a complete "provider" section.

```
# To improve... try to use dynamic block
# It looks to be not possible. Could be necessary to auto-generate this scetion with external script
# provider "azurerm" {  
#   features {}
#   dynamic "spoke" {
#     for_each = var.spoke_networks
#     content {
#       subscription_id = spoke.value["subscription_id"]
#       alias = spoke.value["subscription_alias"]
#     }
#   }
# }
```

What I would like to achieve is to just feed my variable(spoke_networks) with a new entry, and terraform creates a new provider.
the variable file stucture should be something like this:

```
variable "spoke_networks" {
    description = "List with the properties of the Spoke VNETs"
    type        = list(object({subscription_alias=string ,subscription_id=string , resource_group_name=string , vnet_name=string }))
}
```

Thank you,
VS

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with `terraform`. But possibly you could do it with [terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you please be more detailed, namely, how to do it with terragrunt?